# How to render an Ember template to a string?

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am making a special Ember Handlebars helper. I need to render an Ember template, and get it either as a string or HTML that I can manipulate. I can't find how to do that, any suggestions? I have access to the compiled template inside the helper.

Comment: The answer for [Compile Ember template string and running it programmatically, without an Ember application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274086/compile-ember-template-string-and-running-it-programmatically-without-an-ember) is asynchronous, which will be problematic for rendering with a handlebars helper, wouldn't it? Is there no synchronous way of doing this?