# How can I use templates outside of the render pipeline

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I have an event where I need to insert a template into space outside of the app. With Ember-CLI we have all these wonderfully pre-compiled templates, so I'm trying to figure out how I can use one.

(Ember-CLI 0.0.42, Ember 1.7.0)

I found I can get the pre-compiled template function like this:

```
import TheTemplate from 'app/templates/the-template';
```

However, if I call it as documented on the Handlebars website, I get an error.

```
var context = { button: "OK" };
var str = TheTemplate(context);

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

So what is the proper way to use these templates?

Comment: Handlebars.template("the-template") also gets the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question, asked in a different way, may have been answered already:

[Compile Ember template string and running it programmatically, without an Ember application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274086/compile-ember-template-string-and-running-it-programmatically-without-an-ember?rq=1)

Using both a template and view, something like this would seem to work from within another view:

```
externalView = this.get("container").lookup("view:the-template");
externalView.setProperties({ button: "OK" });
externalView.appendTo($("#here"));
```

...and then remember to destroy() or destroyElement() later on.

Comment: Just to emphasize, this would only work to render outside of the app.